# Como configurar página personalizada do Error 500?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web.config, página-de-erro

Boa tarde, estou a começar a escrever erros.

No meu web config está instalado da seguinte maneira:

Erro 404

```
 <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Erro/Error-404.html">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Erro/Error-404.html" />         
 </customErrors>
```

Erro 403

```
 <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
      <remove statusCode="403" />
      <error statusCode="403" path="/Erro/Error-403.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />      
    </httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>
```

E para o erro 500 tentativas de diversas formas mas não obtive sucesso!

Alguém pode me auxiliar?

Comment: O que acontece, ele exibe o stack de erro ou redireciona sempre para o 404?

Comment: ele aparece a mensagem de erro 500 padrão

Answer (score 2):

caso use o `customErros` vc precisa fazer o seguinte:

No `FilterConfig.cs` comente essa linha `//filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());`

no web.config adicione isso:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/paginadeerror/Error">
    <error redirect="~/paginadeerror/Error/404" statusCode="403" />
    <error redirect="~/paginadeerror/Error/404" statusCode="404" />
    <error redirect="~/paginadeerror/Error/500" statusCode="500" />
</customErrors>
```

Crie o controller e a view

```
public class paginadeerrorController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Error(int id)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = id;
        return View();
    }
}
```

e caso queira uma view por codigo, vc vai ter que escrever cada ActionResult referente ao codigo, exemplo:

```
    public ActionResult Error404()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

e web vai ficar:

```
<error redirect="~/paginadeerror/Error404" statusCode="404" />
```

Answer (score 0):

No seu `Web.config` deixe o `<httpErrors>` da seguinte forma.

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
  <remove statusCode="500" />
  <remove statusCode="404" />
  <remove statusCode="403" />
  <error statusCode="500" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/Index" />
  <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/NotFound" />
  <error statusCode="403" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/AccessDenied" />
</httpErrors>
```

Altere os `path` para a rota da sua `view` de erro.